How to parse date from data after page loading
After page loading, the html rendered is like that
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h3>
<p>Meeting scheduled for 7/19/26, You should receive the email confirmation shortly.</p>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h4>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>

Now I want to change the date format like this July 19th via jQuery or JavaScript so that para should be like that
Meeting scheduled for July 19th, You should receive the email confirmation shortly.


What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Unless you have more structured access to the data, I imagine you'd need to manually parse that value from the text so you can convert it to a Date and format it however you like.  Where specifically do you get stuck?

I am just basic developer and not sure how to do this.

July 19th, your not bothered about the year 2026?

its requirement. so not bothered by year

@user3376865: "not sure how to do this" - One step at a time.  Break apart the problem into smaller pieces.  Your first piece is to read this value from the markup.  jQuery provides functionality for selecting an element and reading the text of that element.  When you make an attempt, do you get stuck somewhere?

yes, I am unable to parse date from string.

@user3376865: What attempt have you made and in what way is that code not working as expected?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you have encountered, and indicate what that problem is.

Can you try this ?
The output is written on the console as well as the body itself, you can amend the script to suit your needs.


  function getOrdinal(n) {
        let ord        = ["st", "nd", "rd"]
        let exceptions = [11, 12, 13]
        let nth        = ord[(n % 10) - 1] == undefined || exceptions.includes(n % 100) ? "th" : ord[(n % 10) - 1]
        return n + nth
    };

    var temp    = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML 
    temp        = temp.replace(',','');

    var strDate = temp.match(/\d{1,2}\D\d{1,2}\D(\d{4}|\d{2})/g)
    var objDate = new Date(strDate);

    var myDate  = objDate.getDate();
    var myMonth = objDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    var myYear  = objDate.getFullYear();
    
    var myStr   = temp.replace(strDate, myMonth + ' ' + getOrdinal(myDate) + ', ' + myYear + '.');

    console.log(myStr);
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML= myStr;
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h3>
    <p>Meeting scheduled for 7/19/26, You should receive the email confirmation shortly.</p>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h4>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>




you code working as required but when I added one more line in code to fulfill my requirements that line of code not reflecting at front end. here is code  temp.textContent = "myStr"; However the required result printed in console can be seen. I have written this piece of code after console statement.

Try this document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML= myStr

I added my comment above to the script as well.... You can accept my answer if it is OK for you.

to help others can you modify your code little bit more to add year also? like July 19th, 2024

I revised the script above according to your last comment. You can check it again....

@user3376865; has everything settled down?
